# Filter common dates between two arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So i have this project i am working on where i have an array of Javascript objects, and each object contains different entrys:

```
var array_of_objects = [{
    "timeline": [-765, ..., -18342],
    "Date": [2022-01-18 00:00:00:0000Z, ..., 2022-06-03 00:00:00:0000Z],
    ....
},
....
{
    "timeline": [-34, ..., 421],
    "Date": [2022-02-14 00:00:00:0000Z, ..., 2022-05-27 00:00:00:0000Z],
    ....
}]
```

And the dates go in a range from a starting day to an end day, and represent the dates corresponding to the values in timeline. Date and timeline array have the same length.

I have many of these objects and wish to compare them two at a time with some algorithm, but my problem is that the starting and end dates are different for each object.

My goal is to slice them so that they represent the overlapping date range of the two objects, so that the timeline array is sliced by the common dates between the two objects.
Meaning the output should be two arrays of the same length, containing the values of `timeline` sliced by the overlapping dates between the two objects.

I have absolutely no idea, i started with an extremely clunky if statement, but that just started looking ugly and only sometimes gave the right result. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Post what you've tried as a [mcve]. Also, is there a logical pattern to timeline?

Comment: If I get what you are saying, each timeline element has a corresponding date element in its array, and you want to join all the timelines together, all the dates together, and remove duplicate matching timeline-date pairs.